# deleting a remote branch after merge

Tags: git

I am using git and been working on a local branch which is also pushed to the remote.

After some commits, I have merged it to the dev as:

```
git checkout dev
git merge --no-ff myFeature
```

Now, I push as:

```
git push origin dev
```

My question is that I do not want to work on the feature branch anymore and I have deleted it locally. Is it safe to delete it on the remote as well? I am worried I might be breaking git somehow....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To really understand the answer, their is a notion that you must understand with git.
Git store history as a tree like that (more exactly a `DAG` --Directed acyclic graph--):

[image: A git Dag]

and branches (local, remote or tags) are pointers towards commits.
Every commit not pointed by a pointer could be "considered" (not exactly but a detail in our case) lost.

You should also know that a commit point toward its parent(s) (that's how a graph is *computingly* stored) so could never be "lost" since there is a pointer to it through a more or less long chain of commits.

Once you understand that, you understand that C5 (which was pointed by `iss53` --your `feature` branch in your case--), is pointed by your merge commit C6 which is pointed by the ref `master`.

So you could delete `iss53` which change nothing in term of commits pointed so you will loose nothing!

Comment: Couldn't agree more, understanding the DAG is key to understanding Git.

Answer (score 2):

If you merged the branch and pushed to the remote, then it's safe to remove the branch on the remote.

Comment: @Luca: Agreed, it's safe.  In fact, since you've used the `--no-ff` option, Git's history will reflect you merged in a separate branch and will show the commits in that branch.  FWIW, the specific syntax to delete your remote from the command line is `$ git push --delete origin myFeature`.

Comment: @MikeAtkisson Thanks for clarifying :)